# How to fix "NameError: uninitialized constant Uglifier"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I run `rake db:setup` I get the error:

> deploy@Exchange:~/.rbenv/peatio$ bundle exec rake db:setup
>   peatio_production already exists
>   rake aborted!
>   NameError: uninitialized constant Uglifier
>   /home/deploy/.rbenv/peatio/config/environments/production.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>`
>   
>  /home/deploy/.rbenv/peatio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval`
>   
> /home/deploy/.rbenv/peatio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure`
>   
> /home/deploy/.rbenv/peatio/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in `configure`
>   
> /home/deploy/.rbenv/peatio/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>`

Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you have some syntax somewhere, most likely in a JS file. Check the last files you have worked on and look for a syntax error.